# Как получить сумму всех элементов массива в twig?

Tags: массивы, twig, php

В шаблон передается массив areas, необходимо проссумировать все элементы и вывести результат. Стандартный вариант:

```
{% set ar = 0 %}
{% for area in areas %}
      {% ar = ar + area %}
{% endfor %}
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ ar }}</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

не работает. Пишет ошибку - неизвестный тег ar.
Считать необходимо именно в шаблоне. Может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пропустили присвоение внутри цикла.

```
{% set ar = 0 %}
{% for area in areas %}
    {% set ar = ar + area %}
{% endfor %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ar }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Вот так все работает.